# My select query is removing null value row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

so my oracle query is to display all customer IDs, customer names, and sales rep names using customer and emp tables but only if the rep’s name does not have R as the last or before the last character and to list all customers, even if they do not have a sales rep.
So, I wrote the below query-

```
select c.custid "Customer  ID"
,c.name "Customer Name"
,s.ename "Sales Rep"
from customer c
left outer join emp s
on c.repid = s.empno
where 
(s.ename not like '%R'
and s.ename not like '%R_')
order by c.name ;
```

This query should give me below result-
[image: Desired Result]

However, it is giving me below result. It is removing null value record even though I used left join! I dont understand why!
[image: my result]

Please help!

Regards,
Layla

Answer (score 1):

Put the filters into the `JOIN` condition:

```sql
select c.custid AS "Customer  ID"
,      c.name   AS "Customer Name"
,      s.ename  AS "Sales Rep"
from   customer c
       left outer join emp s
       on (   c.repid = s.empno
          AND s.ename not like '%R'
          AND s.ename not like '%R_')
order by c.name;
```

If you have the filters in the `WHERE` clause then `s.ename` must be non-`NULL` and it effectively converts the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`.

---

Alternatively, you could use the filters in the `WHERE` clause and add another filter to check for `NULL` values:

```sql
select c.custid AS "Customer  ID"
,      c.name   AS "Customer Name"
,      s.ename  AS "Sales Rep"
from   customer c
       left outer join emp s
       on (c.repid = s.empno)
WHERE (   s.ename not like '%R'
      AND s.ename not like '%R_')
OR    s.empno IS NULL             -- Check for outer joined rows
order by c.name;
```

But it usually more comprehensible to put those filters into the join condition.

Comment: Thanks MTO, how can I put those filters into the join condition?

Comment: @Layla Exactly as I show you in the answer.